# Adjust the distance between zticks and Z axis in the 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

The zticks and Z axis are overlapping in a 3D plot. How to adjust the spacing between these two?
I think this is happening because of the because of more number digits after the decimal point.

[image]

Comment: Does the following code improve the situation? `ax.set_zticklabels(ax.get_zticks(), fontdict={'ha':'left'})`

Comment: There is a warning: `UserWarning: FixedFormatter should only be used together with FixedLocator` . Also most of the values of the ticks are omitted and not matching with the data set.

Comment: I'm aware of the warning. If you edit your question and add data and code, I'm sure others will respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the solution suggested by @r-beginners along with `axes.set_zticks` solved the problem i.e., according to [matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) documentation the following code should be used for fixing the zticks position:

```
ax.set_zticks(ticks,  minor=False)
```

Later use the following code to offset the zticks:

```
ax.set_zticklabels(ax.get_zticks(), fontdict={'ha':'left'})
```